# SharedPreference won't apply change (in a fragment)

Tags: android, kotlin

In my Activity there is a ViewPager2 that loads a fragment which shows texts and another fragment which intended to have options such as the size of texts which shows on the other fragment. To make it not have to set the option every time I chose to use SharedPreferences, but it won't take effects. Here is the code:

```
class Options : Fragment() {
   lateinit var binding: OptionsLayoutBinding
   private lateinit var mPreferences: SharedPreferences
   val preferencesEditor: SharedPreferences.Editor get() = mPreferences.edit()

   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       mPreferences = this.requireActivity().getSharedPreferences("pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
   }

   override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
       binding = OptionsLayoutBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
       return binding.root
   }

   override fun onResume() {
       super.onResume()
       binding.radioGroupTextSize.setOnCheckedChangeListener { group, checkedId ->
           preferencesEditor.run{
               when (checkedId) {
                   R.id.textSize_RB1 -> putInt("TXTSZ", 12)
                   R.id.textSize_RB2 -> putInt("TXTSZ", 14)
                   R.id.textSize_RB3 -> putInt("TXTSZ", 16)
                   R.id.textSize_RB4 -> putInt("TXTSZ", 18)
                   R.id.textSize_RB5 -> putInt("TXTSZ", 20)
               }
           }
       }

   override fun onPause() {
       super.onPause()
       preferencesEditor.apply()
       Log.d("PREF", "TEXT SIZE SET TO ${mPreferences.getInt("TXTSZ", 12)}. ")
   }
}
```

.. The Log.d() is there to make sure where the problem happens and the log only says it's 12. It seems SharedPreferences is not saving the value, tt also doesn't take any effects to the target fragment which is meant to display texts in changed size. I wondered if apply() is placed wrong so I tried putting it after every radio button behaviours, which didn't improve the situation at all.

There are many other values neeed to be saved, but working out this one means they would work too, so I simplified the code here.

Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: Probably you are not recreating the view with the new values, your old instance is still running and displaying the old values.

Comment: Did you add breakpoint to be sure that your putInt code is executed ?

Comment: I found out breakpoints not stopping the code execution, and checking the sharedpreferences xml it had no values at all; totally empty!

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem; it creates xml but didn't write anyting on it. I still don't know why it worked that way, perhaps(most likely) it's a spaghetti code, so I just put simple codes that confirms working on an activity. It won't in a fragment, and made a simple change to fix it.

```
lateinit var binding: OptionsLayoutBinding
   var preferencesEditor: SharedPreferences? = null
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       preferencesEditor = activity?.getSharedPreferences("pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
   }

   override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
       binding = OptionsLayoutBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
       return binding.root
   }
```

and putting .apply() after every putInt(). Made a custom function to not repeat it.